# IPython Not opening (invalid syntax)

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ipython

I have installed IPython using the command:

```
 python3.7 -m pip install ipython
```

And it gave the prompt of successful installation as well but when i try to open IPython using the command:

```
python3.7 -m IPython
```

(NOTE: using IPython instead of ipython because that's how it is stored in my system)
I am getting the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 119, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import path as util_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._process_posix import system, getoutput, arg_split, check_pid
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 218
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

Download pexpect4.6 source code from https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/releases/tag/4.6

Extract the source code, get into the folder and install the pexpect by:

`sudo python3.7 setup.py install`

This should solve your problem. :)

Comment: Sorry, but I won't be able to verify the answer as I have to revert back to windows due to touchscreen driver issues